# Can I use `lsof` to reliably determine which local process has connected to my open port?

Tags: authentication, network, detection

Say I'm running a server application on `127.0.0.1:7646` and a local process (possibly owned by a different user) connects to it, I can run

```
lsof -Fp -i TCP@127.0.0.1:7646 -i TCP@127.0.0.1:<ClientPort>
```

which outputs something like

```
p6429
f4
p6433
f5
```

where `p*` are the PIDs of both participants/endpoints.

Now my question is: can I trust `lsof`'s output (provided that nobody modified the `lsof`-binary)? Or in other terms: Could someone without root-permissions manipulate `lsof`s output to display a different PID?

Edit: If this is platform-dependent, I'm specifically interested in macOS, Linux and FreeBSD.

Comment: Oh, this is a misunderstanding – I'm only listening on and interested in connections on the same machine (loopback/localhost)...

Comment: Aha! So you're asking if there are any tricks involving files / symlinks / hardlinks / named pipes / etc that would cause `lsof` to report incorrectly? Interesting question indeed! +1

Comment: Is that edit still in keeping with what you're trying to ask?

Comment: Yes, this is fine; ty 

Comment: My gut says probably not on Linux, unless they can manipulate LSM's or load kernel modules (neither of which actually _require_ root access on Linux, you just have to have the right capabilities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trust the user running lsof and specify the full path (/usr/bin/lsof?), you should be able to trust the output.  If you're aiming for lsof to run as the user who is connecting to your server, it's really difficult to prevent an lsof in their path from running or an alias catching the call first.  Also see 'netstat -A inet -A inet6 -alp'

If you're really paranoid you could check the package manager database (rpm, dpkg, etc) to make sure that the binary hadn't changed since install before calling it (with the full path).